# How do I find a locking doorknob for an existing door with a non-standard backset?

Tags: doors, lock, doorknob

I'm trying to replace a lockless interior door's knob with one with a lock (not a "privacy lock", but an exterior-door-type key lock).  The existing hole and knob has a non-standard backset of about 2-5/8".  I've found plenty of new knobs that are adjustable between the standard sizes of *exactly* 2-3/8" and 2-3/4", but nothing that can be adjusted to something *between* those sizes.

Is there any way to find a knob that will fit without re-drilling or replacing the door?

Comment: I had some exterior doors like this at a previous house.  I drilled new holes.  The trim around the new lock-sets still covered the entire hole, so I didn't consider the slightly-enlarged hole to be a problem.

Comment: Is that 2-5/8 from the short side or the long side? (Door edges are usually tapered.) My suspicion is that a 2-3/4 backset would work fine. Worst case is that you might have to nibble away a little at the hole on the face of the door.

Comment: Try an antique shop or old furnishings store.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I actually bought a new knob and tried both the 2-3/8 and 2-3/4 settings, and neither fit

Comment: @JACK that's a great idea, will look for one in town

Comment: @JeffWheeler Hadn't considered that... I think the existing holes are also on the smaller side, so I expect that could work